# 'Maximum Recursion depth exceeded' whenever I do OOP

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, recursion

```
  File "C:\tv.py", line 20, in set_channel
    self.channel = new_channel
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I am attempting my first OOP problem. The problem in my textbook is:

*"Write a program that simulates a television by creating it as an object. Allow the user to increase/decrease the volume, and set the channel number. Make sure the channel and volume values stay within a valid range."*

**My questions are:**

1. Is my structure broadly correct? (In that I've chosen to make methods for inc/dec volume, etc)
2. Why am I getting the recursion error? I guess it means I'm in an infinite loop of some kind, but I absolutely cannot see it.

My unfinished 'solution':

```
# Television with Classes
# User able to enter a channel number
# and increase/decrease the volume

class Television(object):
    """A TV set."""
    def __init__(self, channel = 1, volume = 20):
        self.channel = channel
        self.volume = volume

    def get_channel(self):
        """Return current channel."""
        return self.channel

    def set_channel(self, new_channel):
        """Set the channel."""
        if 1 < new_channel > 5:
            print "Invalid Channel. Must be between 1-5."
        else:
            self.channel = new_channel

    channel = property(get_channel, set_channel)

    def show_volume(self):
        """Return current volume."""
        return self.volume

    def inc_volume(self):
        """Increase the volume by 1 unit."""
        if self.volume >= 20:
            print "Volume is at maximum: ", get_volume, "\n"
        else:
            self.volume += 1

    def dec_volume(self):
        """Decrease the volume by 1 unit."""
        if self.volume <= 0:
            print "Volume is at minimum: ", get_volume, "\n"
        else:
            self.volume -= 1


sony = Television()
print "Current channel: ", sony.channel
print "Changing channel to 3..."
sony.channel(3)
print "Current channel: ", sony.channel
print "Current volume: ", self.volume
print "Increasing volume..."
sony.inc_volume()
print "Current volume: ", self.volume

raw_input("\n\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Comment: Where is your 'get_volume' method?

Comment: @SlavenTomac I have not made one. I didn't think it was needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your property has the same name as the value you are trying to access with the property. Hence it is recursively trying to get it's own value when you access it.

Renaming the property should resolve it.

Changing the code to be like this:

```
channel = 0
Channel = property(get_channel, set_channel)
```

will stop the recursion from happening. You will have `Channel` as the property (so call this), which accesses the `channel` field with the get/set_channel methods.

Assignment to this property doesn't work with `sony.channel(3)` as well. You'll have to actually assign to the property like any other value:

```
sony.channel = 3
```

or (if you're already changed the property issue)

```
sony.Channel = 3
```

This won't stop the issues you'll have with the volume later on though. `self.volume` is not declared as a field (or as a property for that matter), and the same goes for `get_volume` in the inc/dec_volume functions.

Comment: You should add some code on which line should be changed into what.  Got my ⁺¹ anyway :)

Comment: @Alfe How did you superscript `+1`? :)

Comment: @thefourtheye SO allows basic HTML. There is 'sup' tag to make superscripted text https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup.

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm using the compose key of my keyboard for this. [Compose] [^] [+] and [compose] [^] [1].  It looks like this: ⁺¹ vs. <sup>+1</sup> (which doesn't work as you see).

Answer (score 1):

Problem lays here:

```
def get_channel(self):
    """Return current channel."""
    return self.channel

def set_channel(self, new_channel):
    """Set the channel."""
    if 1 < new_channel > 5:
        print "Invalid Channel. Must be between 1-5."
    else:
        self.channel = new_channel

channel = property(get_channel, set_channel)
```

Every requet of self.channel is running get_channel(), but get_channel() requests for self.channel, and so on.

To avoid this you need to create helper-variable which will store real value of self.channel.

```
self.__channel = None # Field where self.channel will be really stored

def get_channel(self):
    """Return current channel."""
    return self.__channel

def set_channel(self, new_channel):
    """Set the channel."""
    if 1 < new_channel > 5:
        print "Invalid Channel. Must be between 1-5."
    else:
        self.__channel = new_channel

channel = property(get_channel, set_channel) # Public interface
```